# Change base url of oracle apex application

Tags: url, oracle-apex

How to change the base url of my apex application?
Currently the application url has the server name. I do not want everyone to see the server name.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to change your server name, that is not something you will be able to change with a setting. You will need to use a custom DNS to hide your server name.

If you are looking to change the part of the URL after the server name, there are some methods described [here](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4159633/ords-base-url).

Comment: What do I need to do to hide the server name? What do I need to do use a custom DNS